# Layout is not affected by panel.setBackGround(Color.)

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code, and the result is as in the picture (I've not added the repetitive part of the code). Somehow,the panel gets color but the part where the layout is designed. What am I missing?

```
class Elements extends JPanel {

Elements() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("l1");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    add(l1, c);
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("l2");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    add(l2, c);
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Calc");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    Elements elements = new Elements();
    frame.add(p);
    p.add(elements);        
    frame.setSize(1000, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    p.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Elements` class extends `JPanel`. You see the default color of the JPanel, since you didn't set the color.

You can do either:

```
elements.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
```

to specifically set its background.

or

```
elements.setOpaque( false );
```

to make the panel transparent so you will see the background of its parent panel. This is the easies so you don't have to set the background twice if you ever decide to change it.

Comment: It works, indeed. So by extending the class with JPanel, I've added another panel on top on the one from my main method. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your panel p, elements is in the foreground.  try doing `elements.setBackground(Color.blue);` to achieve your desired behaviour.